# React Native - Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly

Tags: android, ios, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup debug environment for `react-native` on **VS Code** on Mac.
This is **launch.json** :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react",
            "target": "simulator"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Android",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
}
```

On debugging I am getting the error - **Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly.** along with one more error.

[image]

I have opened an issue on [**Github**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/612#issuecomment-349862629) as well but haven't received a solution yet.

**Update** : In response to ShaneG answer, I am adding screenshots of project scheme and info.plist

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is strange, I haven't received a single comment/answer for a topic all react-native developers working on mac have probably gone through.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this: in your `.vsCode` folder, see if you have a `.react` folder in there.

If you don't, try running `code .` from the root directory of your project folder. You will need to install the shell command from VSCode if you haven't already (type `shift-command-p` and search for `Shell command: Install code command PATH`).

This was my issue, for whatever reason the `.react` folder was not being created when I opened VSCode from spotlight.

Comment: I ran Shell command: Install code command PATH from VSCode but .react folder still isn't created.

Comment: But later when I ran the project, it worked and now I am able to see the app on simulator. .react folder is still not there in .vscode folder. Any comments on that ?

Comment: It's my understanding that you need a `.react` folder to properly link the packager to the simulator. Otherwise some tools, such as the debugger,  may not work. If you're able to develop normally without this folder you may have a different setup or issue.

Comment: I had to run `export PATH="/home/danny/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"` before running `code .` for it to create .react because I'm using a custom location for npm global packages, I guess it couldn't find react-native-cli because of this.

Comment: Din't help for me, .react folder was created, but launchReactNative.js file is not, still same error

Answer (score 1):

I see its "Debug ios" you ran. Can you make sure its pointing to the correct info.plist file? Many errors can crop up if its pointing to an old info.plist.
I can see on the GitHub issue you posted, when you ran it from the command line it outputted a very useful error.

```
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier 
build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/firstdemo.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Its trying to access the bundleIdentifier but it cannot seem to find it. This info should be inside the info.plist file. Your app might be routed to an old info.plist file that does not have this information.

**How to check if its pointing to the correct info.plist?**

- First before we go into the info.plist, in xcode go to Product -> Scheme 
  -> Edit Scheme. In here go to Run and check what your build config is 
  set to. The error above is coming from Debug, so if your build config 
  is set to Release this may be the issue. This may mean Release has the 
  info.plist and Debug does not have this bundle info because its not 
  built in it.
- In here there is also a "Debug Executable" check box. This may need to 
  be checked
- If none of that works, although it might, maybe check the info.plist inside your project folder in xcode. See if it has a bundle identifier.

I would say the Scheme section is probably the problem so hopefully that helps you!

Comment: I have added screenshots of project scheme and info.plist in my question. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: @Nitish Is this the way you had it, or have you just changed it to these settings?

Comment: @Nitish In any case your bundle Identifier looks strange. I am not sure what it should be but mine is just "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)". Maybe try changing that unless you know what it should be.

Comment: I tried replacing it with myapp. But still it didn't work.

Comment: Bounty time is getting expired. So I am rewarding you the bounty. But since I am not able to solve this, I'll wait for more solutions.

Comment: @Nitish Try changing it to $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER). It should not be your project name. I know that much. I will keep searching myself

Answer (score 1):

Delete React Native Tools extension from vs-code and then reinstall it.

It works fine post that.